# Can we use 3 "to be" in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

> The correlation **was** higher when the angles that **were** formed between two variables **were** narrower.

Can we use "to be" 3x times the above sentence?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your sentence. Why do you think it's should not be possible?

Comment: It would be a bit picky, but I would call *3x times* redundant, and use either *3x* or *3 times*.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is OK, but you could break up the repetition by leaving out the second *were*:

> The correlation was higher when the angles formed between two variables were narrower.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not really about the number of verbs per *sentence*, but the number of verbs per *clause*. Here, you have three clauses of various kinds, and three forms of *be*, one in each clause, so the answer is 'yes' (although you can omit the second one).

The main clause is: 'The correlation *was* higher ...'

The second (or third) is: 'when the angles ... *were* narrower'

The third (or second) is: '[that *were*] formed between two variables ...'

It is often possible to omit the relative pronoun (that) and the verb *be* in relative clauses like the one you have.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is correct in it's grammatical sense.

> Can we use "to be" 3x times the above sentence?

I didn't understand why you want to use `to be` 3x times in the sentence.

If you're asking whether one can use multiple forms/tenses of words (`were` and `was`) in a single sentence multiple times, then **Yes,** you can so long as the sentence is making grammatical sense.